# Nativescript local css files

Tags: nativescript

When using sidekick to build the nativescript app , the page-specific css files(css files in the same directory) are not being loaded. These work on the emulator but not when building and running on the device.

My directory structure is :

```
/app
  /pages
    /sample
        sample.xml
        sample.js
        sample.css
```

Comment: Did you try using the CLI (`tns [build|run] [ios|android] --bundle`), does the issue still persist?

Answer (score 0):

another way i to put all your css in `app.css` it is loaded on start and accessible globally